NestJS Return Null in Body using DTO
I have a problem when I creating new resource with command nest g resource or using nest g module product the file already generated but the problem happen when I try to use POST request in the postman (my case is using hoppscotch and postman). but its return {} every time I connected to createProductDto using console log to check the request body is
Product Controller
import { Body, Controller, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { CreateProductDto } from './dto/create-product.dto';
import { ProductService } from './product.service'

@Controller('api/products')
@ApiTags('products')
export class ProductController {
    constructor(private readonly productService: ProductService) { }

    @Post()
    async create(@Body() createProductDto: CreateProductDto) {
        console.log(createProductDto);
        return this.productService.create(createProductDto);
    }
}

Product Module
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ProductService } from './product/product.service';
import { ProductController } from './product/product.controller';
import { PrismaModule } from 'src/prisma/prisma.module';

@Module({
  providers: [ProductService],
  controllers: [ProductController],
  imports: [PrismaModule]
})
export class ProductsModule { }

Create Product DTO
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class CreateProductDto {
    @ApiProperty()
    title: string;

    @ApiProperty({ required: false })
    description: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    body: string;

    @ApiProperty({ required: false, default: false })
    published?: boolean = false;
}

Product Service
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateArticleDto } from 'src/articles/dto/create-article.dto';
import { PrismaService } from 'src/prisma/prisma.service';
import { CreateProductDto } from './dto/create-product.dto';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) { }

    create(createProductDto: CreateProductDto) {
        return this.prisma.product.create({ data: createProductDto });
    }
}

already try it 4 time already to generate new resource but its still the same, restart Pc and service still no change
{
  "name": "Amazing Product",
  "description": "This is a fantastic product you'll love!",
  "price": 10000,
  "image": "https://example.com/product-image.jpg", 
  "categoryId": "1"
}

but when I use @Body() createProductDto: any the request is available
when i submit the data i recieve error
  10 create(createProductDto: CreateProductDto) {
→ 11     return this.prisma.product.create({
           data: {
         +   name: String
           }
         })

Argument `name` is missing.

because the body request is always {}

Adding class-validator helps keep your data in check and avoids unexpected blanks in requests.
This could really help solve the issue you're facing. If your data doesn't meet the expected format, you'll be notified directly, so you can quickly see where you need to make corrections.

WOW i spent like 3 hour and your solution is the best sir, i cant believe its work, thanks mate
